# express.js req.body undefined in middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently facing a problem in my node application.

while trying to use middleware in a post request the req.body becomes undefined.

for example;

```
router.post('/newpost', ensureAuthenticated, createPost, upload.single('file'), async (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
}

async function createPost(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body);
    next();
}
```

when the createPost function runs it logs req.body as undefined.
but when req.body gets logged inside the router.post it is defined.

is it something i'm missing? or is this just not possible to do.

also i've ensured that i've included bodyparser and initialized it before my routes.

Comment: It’s a comum mistake, but to get the `body` you need to tell express that you want to parse it adding `app.use(express.json())` before your routes 

Comment: i've done this, and like i explained i can get the body.req inside the router.post but in my middleware it's undefined

Comment: just for fun, attach the body object to res.locals and see if you get it in createPost

Comment: if i attach body object to res.locals it still comes back as undefined

Comment: what if, creating the createPost as an arrow function:
const createPost = (req, res, next) => ....

Comment: still undefined with arrow function

Comment: lol sorry not sure what is going on there... the code seems absolutely fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I've just tested and all works fine, with my suggestion in the comment

here's the content of my test:

my `index.js`

```js
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router()
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002

app.use(express.json())

const createPost = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('createPost', req.body)
    next()
}

router.post('/newpost', createPost, (req, res) => {
    console.log('/nextpost', req.body)
    res.json({ message: 'ok' })
})

app.use('/', router)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(
        `server ready at http://localhost:${PORT}`
    )
})
```

and a simple [REST Client file](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client)

```
@HOST = http://localhost:3002

POST {{HOST}}/newpost
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "fname": "Bruno",
    "lname": "Alexandre",
    "nick": "balexandre"
}
```

and the result is

```sh
❯ node .\index.js
server ready at http://localhost:3002
createPost { fname: 'Bruno', lname: 'Alexandre', nick: 'balexandre' }
/nextpost { fname: 'Bruno', lname: 'Alexandre', nick: 'balexandre' }
```

and the response of the call

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 16
ETag: W/"10-/VnJyQBB0+b7i4NY83P42KKVWsM"
Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2021 19:59:21 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "message": "ok"
}
```

screenshot (click for full image)

[image]

---

### Warning

make sure you're passing `Content-Type: application/json` in your `POST` request, remember that you told Express that you wanted the body parsed as `.json()` so make sure it knows you're passing json as the request body

a bit more information... the `req.body` is only `undefined` if I do not use the parser, like:

[image]

---

## Added

a GitHub repository with working solution > https://github.com/balexandre/so65907925

Comment: ah ok it does work like you said, I've realised that my problem is because I'm using multer to upload an image and inside of my post request i have to use enctype="multipart/form-data", which causes the req.body to be undefined inside the middleware. I'm attempting to upload an image as part of a post but use the postid as the filename of the image. which means i need to create the post before calling upload.single(). do you have any idea how i could do this?

Comment: why do you need to it in a middleware? you can create the post and work on the file in the same endpoint/function... I'll update my example

Comment: @teka created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/balexandre/so65907925) with a working example

Comment: Thanks for this! really appreciate it.